# Android Studio LogCat doesnt display new lines

Tags: android, android-studio

If I try to `Log.e` or `Log.d` something that stretches to a few lines, only the first line is shown in my LogCat. This has been happening for a month now.
How do I overcome this?

Example:

I have a list of `WorkDay` objects, whose `toString()` implementation looks like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(50);
    stringBuilder.append("\n\nWorkDay string representation: ");
    stringBuilder.append("\nworkEntries: ");
    stringBuilder.append(workEntries);
    stringBuilder.append("\ndate: ");
    stringBuilder.append(date);
    stringBuilder.append("\nisUpdated: ");
    stringBuilder.append(isUpdated);
    stringBuilder.append("\nshiftCode: ");
    stringBuilder.append(shiftCode);
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

When i log.e a list of those, I used to get logcat output something like this:

```
Log.e: list {
    work day representation {
    bla bla bla bla 
    bla bla }, 
    work day representation{
    bla bla bla bla
    bla bla bla }
```

And now, my otput looks like this:

```
Log.e: list {
Log.e: whatever next output is.
```

What I think is happening is, that LogCat trims new lines. How do I make it show them.

Comment: Try to use simply stringBuilder.append("\n");

Comment: Just tried that, no luck.

Comment: Than try this: stringBuilder.append(Html.fromHtml("<br>"));

Comment: Wow! This worked! I wonder why did the old way of this stop working...

Comment: If it workrd, maybe you can accpet my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The response for this problem is: stringBuilder.append(Html.fromHtml("<br>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the marked answer is just a solution if I make my own logs. When I have 3rd party code I still have the problem. I observed that the newline separated lines are swallowed only in Android Studio (1.5 for me) but e.g. Android Device Monitor shows the correct output.
It's a workaround to switch to ADM for logs but veeery unconvenient.